# Why isn't my menu sliding to the left?

Tags: android, animation, menu

i followed a tutorial for a sliding menu:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYPmRhiUMOI

The Problem is, he slides his menu from left to the right while at the same time sliding the Content from left to right. What i Need is to slide the menu from right to left, so i customized his code:

```
public class FlyOutMenu extends LinearLayout {


public FlyOutMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public FlyOutMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context, attrs);
}

public FlyOutMenu(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private View menu, content;

public static int menuMargin = 700;
private static final int menuAnimationDuration = 700;
private static final int menuAnimationPollingIntervall = 16;


public static enum MenuState {
    CLOSED, OPEN, CLOSING, OPENING;
}

protected int currentContentOffset = 0;
public static MenuState menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSED;

protected Scroller newAnimationScroller = new Scroller(this.getContext(), new SmoothInterpolator());

protected Runnable animationRunnable = new AnimationRunnable();
protected Handler animationHandler = new Handler();

protected class SmoothInterpolator implements Interpolator {

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (float) (Math.pow(input -1 , 5) + 1);
    }



}


@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.menu = this.getChildAt(0);
    this.content = this.getChildAt(1);

    this.menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if(changed)
        this.calculateChildDimensions();

    this.menu.layout(left + DialogBox.screenWidth/2, top, right, bottom);
    this.content.layout(left - this.currentContentOffset, top, right - this.currentContentOffset, bottom);
}

private void calculateChildDimensions() {
    this.content.getLayoutParams().width = this.getWidth();
    this.content.getLayoutParams().height = this.getHeight();

    this.menu.getLayoutParams().width = DialogBox.screenWidth/2;
    this.menu.getLayoutParams().height = this.getHeight();
}

public void toggleMenu() {
    switch (menuCurrentState) {
    case CLOSED:
        menuCurrentState = MenuState.OPENING;
        this.menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        newAnimationScroller.startScroll(0, 0, -this.menu.getWidth(), 0, menuAnimationDuration);
        break;

    case OPEN:
        menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSING;
        newAnimationScroller.startScroll(this.currentContentOffset, 0, -this.currentContentOffset, 0, menuAnimationDuration);

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    this.animationHandler.postDelayed(animationRunnable, menuAnimationPollingIntervall);
}

private void adjustContentPosition(boolean isAnimationActive) {
    int scrollerOffset = this.newAnimationScroller.getCurrX();
    this.content.offsetLeftAndRight(scrollerOffset - this.currentContentOffset);

    this.currentContentOffset = +scrollerOffset;

    this.invalidate();

    if(isAnimationActive)
        this.animationHandler.postDelayed(this.animationRunnable, menuAnimationPollingIntervall);
    else
        this.onMenuTransitionComplete();
}

private void onMenuTransitionComplete() {
    switch(menuCurrentState){
        case OPENING:
            menuCurrentState = MenuState.OPEN;
            break;

        case CLOSING:
            menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSED;
            this.menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        default:
            break;
    }

}

protected class AnimationRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean isAnimationActive = FlyOutMenu.this.newAnimationScroller
                .computeScrollOffset();
        FlyOutMenu.this.adjustContentPosition(isAnimationActive);
    }
}
```

}

There are two `views`. One is the `Content` and one is the `menu`. Both should slide from right to left. Without Animation everything works fine. **But with Animation my `content-view` slides perfectly from right to left, where my `menu-view` appears immediatly. I want both to slide!**

I created a enum with four states:

`OPEN` menu is opened.
`CLOSE` menu is closed.
`OPENING` menu is currently opening.
`CLOSING` menu is currently closing.

For sliding a created a scroller called `newAnimationScroller`. To update the UI at specific times i created a Handler called `animationHandler` which uses a Runnable called `animationRunnable`.

`currentContentOffset` is the Offset of the content relative to his parent.

I toogle `toggleMenu()` from an activity if i click a specific button. Then `newAnimationScroller.startScroll(..);` starts the Animation.

I tried to explain everything to make it fast and easy for you to understand the code and be able to Support me.

If there are any questions feel free to ask.

**My Question**:

Somewhere i'm missing a Detail it Looks like he's only animating the content and not the menu.
Once again, content is sliding, menu is appearing immediatly. **What i want:** Content and Menu sliding from right to left.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: you should be using the NavigationDrawer http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: @tyczj Thank you for your Response. I don't want to use it. Due to the Android docs it's only for Navigation but with my menu i don't want to navigate i want set Options and so on. So please if you got time have a short look over my code, i think i'm just missing a small Detail but i can't figure it out

Comment: technically yes it is only for navigation, you can put whatever you want in there.

Comment: @tyczj does the main Content Need to be wrapped by a framelayout? I'm not really familar with FrameLayouts. And do i Need a actionbar for a navigationdrawer? Or does a simple button for opening an closing do the trick?

Comment: I believe you need an action bar though I never tried without. the main content does not have to be a framelayout it can be a linear layout or relative layout

Comment: @tyczj ok and that's exactly the Problem, i don't want an actionbar in my activity... but i will do some Research about it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you want to use is called **Navigation Drawer**.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) from the official Android Dev page on how to create a Navigation Drawer. It has also a great **example** to download.

Use it, you won't regret it. For me it works perfectly!
You can put anything in there really - not just navigate through items, but `onClick`, you could do whatever you want. If you want `Options`. Create an item `Options` in your **Navigation Drawer**, and by clicking it open a `Options Fragment` (for example) and do whatever you want inside there.